# Dynamically adding a <webview> doesn't work

Tags: javascript, webview, handlebars.js, electron

In my **Electron** app, I'm looking to dynamically add `<webview>` via HTML files, so that they are rendered in a process different from the main renderer.

I use Handlebars to manage my templates in Javascript.

When I add a `<webview>` dynamically, it doesn't work.

In my renderer, I do that:

```
// library inclusion

let templateElement = document.createElement('template')
templateElement.innerHTML = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('template').innerHTML)(data) // data contain the id (myWebview) and html (file://[...])
let content = templateElement.content
document.querySelector('#myDiv').appendChild(content.querySelector('#myWebview')) // here, the <webview> is created and placed in the right position

let webview = document.querySelector('webview') // return the <webview>
webview.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
    // this event never called
    webview.loadURL(webview.getAttribute('src'))
})
```

Here, is my `.html`:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <webview id="{{id}}" src="{{html}}"></webview>
</script>
```

**EDIT**

When I add `<webview>` directly to HTML, it works correctly. And when I change `<webview>` by `<iframe>` it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `<script>` tag prevents `<webview>` from being taken into account by electron.

To get around the problem, I put the `<webview>` tag directly in HTML and retrieve it with JavaScript (without using Handlebars).